# Caching a specific path despite catchall lambda proxy in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

On an API gateway stage, I have the resource /{proxy+} defined and for ANY method (GET, POST, etc.)

Is it still possible to selectively enable caching, i.e for a single path (“api/path”)? If so, how can it be done?